# Some properties in Projective Geometry

Tags: discrete-mathematics, projective-geometry, affine-geometry, algebraic-graph-theory, matroids

I am trying to understand the following two Propositions in James Oxley's book ["Matroid Theory"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199603391)

**Prop. 6.1.3**

Let $M$ be a simple rank-r matroid and $\mathbb F$ be a field. The following statements are equivalent:

(i) $M$ is $\mathbb F$-representable.

(ii) $PG(r - 1, \mathbb F)$ has a finite subset $T$ such that $M \cong PG( r - 1, \mathbb F)|T.$

(iii) For some $m \geq r,$ there is a finite subset $S$ of $PG(m - 1, \mathbb F)$ such that $M \cong PG( m - 1, \mathbb F)|S.$

**So, my understanding is that $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ are saying almost the same thing i.e., $(ii)$ is a special case of $(iii)$ when $m = r.$ Am I correct?**

**Prop. 6.1.4**

Let $k$ be a non-negative integer. When $\mathbb F$ is the finite field $GF(q):$

$(i)$ The number of rank-k flats in $PG(r - 1, q)$ is the Gaussian coefficient ${r \brack k}_q.$

$(ii)$ The number of $k$-element independent sets in  $PG(r - 1, q)$ is $$\frac{1}{k!}\frac{q^r - 1}{q - 1}\frac{q^r - q}{q - 1} \dots \frac{q^r - q^{k-1}}{q - 1}.$$

$(iii)$ The number of $k$-element circuits in  $PG(r - 1, q)$ is 0 for $k <3$ and is $$\frac{1}{k!(q - 1)}(q^r - 1)(q^r - q)\dots (q^r - q^{k-2} \text{   for  } k \geq 3.$$

I want to:

Describe  $PG(r - 1, q)/I$ for a $k$- element independent set $I$ in  $PG(r - 1, q).$

**My guess is:**

Using the first Prop.(ii),if we denote all the independent sets of  $PG(r - 1, q)$ by $\mathcal{I}$ then $PG(r - 1, q)|(\mathcal{I} - I)$ is isomorphic to a simple matroid of rank r  - r(I).

I can also say that by (ii) in the second proposition   The number of $k$-element independent sets in  $PG(r - 1, q)$ is $$\frac{1}{k!}\frac{q^r - 1}{q - 1}\frac{q^r - q}{q - 1} \dots \frac{q^r - q^{k-1}}{q - 1} - 1.$$

I am not sure if what I am saying above is correct or no, could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: The internet is big enough for full words, and if your title confuses people, people who can help might akip it, and people who can't might waste their time reading the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is the editing for the title better now or I shall edit more Thomas?